# insert a text after text on line number in bash

Tags: linux, sed, awk, dns

I'm trying to add a master dns ip address in the named.conf file located on line 11. The text on this line is:

```
listen-on port 53 {127.0.0.1; }
```

I want to add the ipaddress after; to make:

```
listen-on port 53 {127.0.0.1; ipaddress; }
```

How would i do such a thing with sed or awk on line 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed '11s/}[ ]*$/ip_address;}/' named.conf
```

To do the in-place edit:

```
sed -i '11s/}[ ]*$/ip_address}/' named.conf
```